# Is there a way to use a texture for sun light?

Tags: texturing, lighting

I would like to have shadows (from clouds) all over a large scene. Instead of using a gobo in front of an area light for example, is it possible to just use a noise texture with the *Sun* light?

I already enabled nodes, and it works with *Point* or *Spot* lights but I couldn't manage to have any results with the *Sun*.

Comment: This is not possible, you will need a workaround. See:
https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/24552/93111

Comment: Yes, it seems the solution from that post is acceptable ('You can project an image from a plane with a simple Transparent BSDF setup between any light and your subject.'). Thanks!